# How to remove the white background from my table

Tags: r, ggpubr

I have to draw a table. I wrote the following code:

```
library(ggpubr)

ds12 <- c("N of individuals", "Eff N after removing Ref", "N of matched sex individuals", "N of failing sex check")
ds13 <- c(903, 893, 892, 1)
ds14 <- cbind(ds12, ds13)
colnames(ds14) <- NULL

ggtexttable(ds14, rows = NULL, theme = ttheme("mBlue", base_size = 30))
```

I got the following table:
[image]

Is it possible to remove the white background to have something like that?

[image]

Here the link of the ggtexttable() function from the ggpubr package:
[https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggtexttable.html#arguments](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could save it with `ggsave` and specify the width and height like this:

```r
library(ggpubr)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ds12 <- c("N of individuals", "Eff N after removing Ref", "N of matched sex individuals", "N of failing sex check")
ds13 <- c(903, 893, 892, 1)
ds14 <- cbind(ds12, ds13)
colnames(ds14) <- NULL

ggtexttable(ds14, rows = NULL, theme = ttheme("mBlue", base_size = 30)) +
  theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))

ggsave("table.png", width = 16, height = 9)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

All whitespace is gone.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I had to view the table using r markdown, it would be sufficient adding "+ theme(plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))" to remove the white background?

Comment: @Khaleesi95, Yes you are right!